# Can a UK PSW visa holder do odd jobs?

Tags: united-kingdom

I wanted to know if someone completes his studies in UK and applies for Post study work visa and gets it.

If he searches for work relevant to his degree but he cant find or is in the process of finding one, then can he do odd jobs like food delivery or working in a grocery stuffs like that to sustain himself till he finds the actual job related to his degree or even if he doesnt find the actual job can he work in odd jobs categories till he has the PSW permit?
ـIf yes how much would be the limit of hours?

Comment: What is it that you need to know that isn't covered in the Immmigration Rules, appendix Graduate, section GR 8.2? https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-graduate

Comment: Not helpfull sorry please read the question again

Comment: If GR 8.2 is not an answer, could you improve your question? And that links has the official rules, if the rules are not enough, you should ask an immigration lawyers (and not random guys on internet)

Comment: Please can you clarify if the person in question already have a Graduate visa in hand (or at least been told the application is successful)? As it is currently written, the header asks for what happens if the answer to the question above is "yes" (of which @GiacomoCatenazzi 's comments apply), and the body asks for what happens if the answer is "no" (of which existing student visa rules likely applies).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read [this page which gives and overview of the Graduate Visa](https://www.gov.uk/graduate-visa), which is the correct name of what is often called "Post Study Work". Check that you are eligible for a Graduate Visa. The conditions are:

> - you’re in the UK
> - your current visa is a Student visa or Tier 4 (General) student visa
> - you studied a UK bachelor’s degree, postgraduate degree or other eligible course for a minimum period of time with your Student visa or Tier 4 (General) student visa
> - your education provider (such as your university or college) has told the Home Office you’ve successfully completed your course
> - You must apply before your Student visa or Tier 4 (General) student visa expires.

Regarding the things you asked about:

- You do not need a job to apply for a Graduate Visa. In fact you need to get a graduate visa before you start a job.
- You are not restricted to working in the field of your qualification once you get the Graduate Visa. You can do "odd jobs" if you want.
- You can stay in the UK while you await a decision on the Graduate Visa, but...
- You cannot work before you get the Graduate Visa, even "odd jobs", unless your student visa permitted you to work.